# migration from table to table php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This code is supposed to take the lignes from table `content_copy_f` that has the same `idparent` as `idcontent` in table `content_copy_p` and insert the `img1` that are from `f` to `p(img1,img2,img3)`.
 It's like you can say if we have 3 lignes in `f` the 3 `img1` in `f` will go in `img1,img2,img3` of `p` like ligne of `p` is devised in 3 lignes in `f` ,the code works but it only enter `img1` in `p`:

```
//save images in the field spe
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 //I define the variable $image
 $image=" ";
 //to handle every picture
 $legende=" ";
 $cont=$row['Co'];
 //id bch i7ot image fi blastha las9a
 $id=$row['idParent']or die(mysqli_error($con));
//3la hasab count dyal chal kin man mara 
 for($i=1;$i<=$cont;$i++){

 if($i==3){$i=$cont;}
 else{
 //legende et image 
     $image =$row['img'.$i];
     $legende=$row['legende'.$i];

     echo $cont."|".$image."|".$legende."<br>";

                                                    //update image o legende bi contenu li jay man content
 mysqli_query($con,"update content_copy_p set img".$i."='".$image."',legende".$i."='".$legende."' where content_copy_p.idContent=".$id."");

     }
                              }
                                          }
```

//fin copie image :)

Comment: How much does $cont return when you echo it?

Comment: is shows betwene 1 and 3